# how to add conatiner box in my home page below app bar (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, box

i have a created an home page with app bar, bottom navigation bar,and a drop down menu.
when i created a container box with it it isn't appearing on my screen. either it overlays the       screen or it exceed the pixels and goes to the extreme right side.someone give me a solution and   code and tell me where to add it please! (i have added two images also below one how i want and the other one how i got)

```
Expanded(child: Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
alignment: Alignment.center,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.indigo,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
Radius.circular(10.0)),
),
child: Text("\$27693.78"),
),
),


THIS IS THE CODE I GAVE FOR CONTAINER, THE WHOLE CODE FOR THE PAGE IS GIVEN BELOW

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
const dashboard({super.key});


@override
State<dashboard> createState() => _dashboardState();
}

class _dashboardState extends State<dashboard> {

int index=0;
final screens = [
Center(child: Text('DASHBOARD', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25))),
Center(child: Text('POS', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25))),
Center(child: Text('ITEMS', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25))),
Center(child: Text('LIMITED STOCKS', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25))),
];

int _value = 1;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
home: Scaffold(appBar: 
AppBar(
 backgroundColor: Colors.white,
title: Text(''),
actions: <Widget>[
Icon(
Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
color: Colors.indigo,
),
Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
Icon(
Icons.list,
color: Colors.indigo,
),
Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
],
),
body :Row (
children: <Widget>[Row
(children:
[Image.asset('assets/increase.png', width: 30,),
('Revenue Statistics',
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.black,fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
),
),],),
Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, bottom: 25,)
),
Expanded(child: DropdownButton(
value: _value,
items: [
DropdownMenuItem(
child: Text('Overall'),
value: 1,
),
DropdownMenuItem(
child: Text('OverallA'),
value: 2,
),
],
onChanged: ( value){
setState(() {
_value = _value;
});
},
hint: Text('Select item'),
),
),
Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1)),
DecoratedBox(decoration:BoxDecoration(
borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(5),
),
),
 Expanded(child: Container(
margin:EdgeInsets.all(10),
padding:EdgeInsets.all(10),
alignment:Alignment.center,
decoration:BoxDecoration
(color:Colors.indigo,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
Radius.circular(10.0)),
),
child: Text("\$27693.78"),
),
),
],
),
 bottomNavigationBar:
NavigationBarTheme(
data: NavigationBarThemeData(
indicatorColor: Colors.indigo,
labelTextStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
TextStyle(fontSize: 14,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,color: Colors.grey),
),
),child:
selectedIndex: index,
onDestinationSelected: (index)=>
setState(() => this.index = index),
destinations: [
NavigationDestination(
icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
label: 'Dashboard',
),
NavigationDestination(
icon: Icon(Icons.point_of_sale),
label: 'pos',
),
NavigationDestination(
icon: Icon(Icons.list),
label: 'items',
),
NavigationDestination(
icon: Icon(Icons.inventory),
label:
'limitedstocks',
),
],
),),
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
onPressed: (){},
child: Icon(
Icons.qr_code_scanner,
color: Colors.white,
),
backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
tooltip: 'Scan QR',
elevation: 5,
),
floatingActionButtonLocation:FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
),
);
}
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejV57.jpg)
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejw0J.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Updated code:

```
class DashBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashBoard({super.key});

  @override
  State<DashBoard> createState() => _DashBoardState();
}

class _DashBoardState extends State<DashBoard> {
  int index = 0;
  final screens = [
    const Center(child: Text('DASHBOARD', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25))),
    const Center(child: Text('POS', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25))),
    const Center(child: Text('ITEMS', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25))),
    const Center(child: Text('LIMITED STOCKS', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25))),
  ];

  int _value = 1;
  Map<String, Color> cardDataList = {
    '27639.78': Colors.indigoAccent,
    '31193.78': Colors.orangeAccent,
    '29474.78': Colors.blueAccent,
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              title: const Text(''),
              actions: const <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.list,
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        'assets/increase.json',
                        width: 30,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        'Revenue Statistics',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButton(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          value: _value,
                          items: const [
                            DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: 1,
                              child: Text('Overall'),
                            ),
                            DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: 2,
                              child: Text('OverallA'),
                            ),
                          ],
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _value = _value;
                            });
                          },
                          hint: const Text('Select item'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 200,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: cardDataList.values.length,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => _customCard(
                            cardDataList.values.toList()[index],
                            cardDataList.keys.toList()[index])),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
              tooltip: 'Scan QR',
              elevation: 5,
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.qr_code_scanner,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButtonLocation:
            FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
            bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBarTheme(
              data: NavigationBarThemeData(
                indicatorColor: Colors.indigo,
                labelTextStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                  const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
              child: NavigationBar(
                selectedIndex: index,
                onDestinationSelected: (index) =>
                    setState(() => this.index = index),
                destinations: const [
                  NavigationDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
                    label: 'Dashboard',
                  ),
                  NavigationDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.point_of_sale),
                    label: 'pos',
                  ),
                  NavigationDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                    label: 'items',
                  ),
                  NavigationDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.inventory),
                    label: 'limitedstocks',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }

  Widget _customCard(Color cardColor, String amount) {
    return Container(
      width: 250,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: cardColor,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.monetization_on_rounded,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )),
            Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "\$$amount",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Total Revenue",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And please stop using Padding widget to add space between, you can use SizedBox and if you want to give padding to and widget then add Pending Widget and add the widget in the child.

And class name should be in CamelCase.

Comment: when i give column the drop down widget moves downwards and the box goes to bottom (*i will add the image in the answer)

Comment: can you please add your code properly, it have some widget missing in the code.

Comment: i have added everything, can you please specify what is missing

Comment: you can refer to the above code. add the issue cause of the image, text and dropDown were not in the same row widget, and i have some more code according to your design

Comment: i am very grateful to you, thanks. and please can you tell me how to add a text below the given text in container and an icon also in container as given in the ui model picture

Comment: i want to give different text and colors for different containers and i also want to give the graph could you help me with that also?

Comment: i have updated the code in my answer, made a function that will return the card and there's a list named cardDateList with the amount and color for the card. For the graph you can follow tutorial like these: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-create-flutter-charts-with-charts-flutter/ and https://medium.flutterdevs.com/draw-graph-in-flutter-e15982c63167.  And please don't forget to accept the answer if you found it helpful. happy learning.

Comment: the image.asset is hidden why? it is showing error when i unhide it

Comment: Sorry, i don't have the image so i have used SizedBox instead and forget to replace it. now i've update the answer.

Comment: hey thanks anyway, this has been a great help from you! ;).

Comment: i will come back if i have anymore doubts:)

Comment: hey, iI have created a Navigation drawer and it doesn't pop up from the right side, it pops from the left side. i want my navigation drawer to pop up from the right side of my screen. could you help? if you have an answer please answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76527230/doubts-on-navigation-drawer-in-flutter/76527275#76527275

Comment: hey can u help me with an issue

Comment: hey i have an issue regarding image and gallery button in container box could you help?